# Effects of increasing timeout limit in Apache

Tags: apache, webserver, system-administration

How increase in Apache timeout will effect my system? I have my web server behind the ELB so how their timeouts must be set to make them work properly.

**I want to increase the timeout in Apache from 60 seconds to 100 seconds**

Comment: No general answer is possible. Certainly the system load will rise, if those processes are active. If they only wait, for example for external input, then the load will not increase. Same applies for their memory usage. We cannot know what kind of processes you refer to and why you think about raising that limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing timeout in Apache won't change anything until or unless I change ELB timeout. Because control stays with ELB and Apache timeout should be greater than or equal to ELB's timeout.
If Apache timeout is increased to 100 ELB timeout should be either equal to Apache timeout or a little less (95-100).